# Does cancelling a Foreground Service's notification pull the service out of the foreground?

Tags: android

I understand that the newer Android APIs require you to start an ongoing notification when the foreground service is running to alert the user that something is running.

My users are asking for a way to override this default behavior and hide the notification anyway (understandably).

If I hold a reference to the notification and cancel it after I call startForeground(..), will Android pull the service out of the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is unfortunately no way around this.

Comment: By no do you mean that cancelling it will have no effect or that it will pull the service out of the foreground?

Comment: Canceling with pull service out of the foreground.